# Binary locked itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

after many problems I had to upload my code, I had no problems from apple and finally going to send my app review. But for some strange reason I can not select my binary, it appears locked. First time it happens.

[image]

Of course, as you can see it says "In progress", but we are almost 24 hours. This is new from Apple? because I had never thought that had to wait more than 20 or 30 minutes.

Comment: It's "in process". For a few days, talking with colleagues, it may take a lot of time, where before, less than 30 minutes was enough. It seems that the issue is with "bitcode" (set to YES).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yesterday I had a lot of trouble climbing the binary actually received like 3 post from Apple to fix some problems found, the fix and did not receive more answers, there is nothing more to wait then. I ask that you put in response to close the post. Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binary is *In Process*.
I discussed with a few colleagues that seems to have the same issue.
When before 30 minutes was fairly enough for "iTunes Connect" to process the binary, it seems that currently, it take a lot of more time.
Colleagues seem to point out that the issue is linked to BitCode (enabled).
You just have to wait, or you can reupload with a BitCode set to NO if possible.