# iOS app submission warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store

While submitting the iOS app through Xcode I am having issues. I have uploaded the app using the Xcode. It is done successfully but after logged into the itunesconnect.apple.com it is not allowing me to select the build in the list of version and it is giving a warning also. Could any one have any idea about it? Please help me . Thank you for the valuable time.

Update: Since one day I am waiting for the submission of app. But it is not allowing me to select the radio button and unable to click done button, submit for review. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Wait for a while, it will allow you to select the build for submission.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Waiting since last 30 minutes but not working

Comment: What is your IPA size ?

Comment: BITCODE enabled? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038491/binary-locked-itunes-connect/33040128#33040128

Comment: Sometimes you have to wait for a longer time :)

Answer (score 2):

It will take around 2- 4 hours. Wait Patiently. Mine took around like 6 hours. Donno, why it takes so long these days.

Comment: ok thank you @Abin George. The apple approve process of iOS apps is becoming tough day by day